# How to get the length of the line being read in from fgets and loop over it

Tags: c, for-loop, sizeof, fgets

I'm trying to loop over each character of a line within fgets, but I am running into errors, as I'll explain below.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   char arr[200]
   int currS = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char);
   // call readIt function

}

void readIt(char* argv[], char arr[], int currS) {
  FILE* file;
  file = NULL;
  file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  while(fgets(arr, currS, file) != NULL) 
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++) 
       print each char of current line
}
```

When I do the for loop over each line, each line output will be the length of the very FIRST line in the file. The # of times the for loop iterates never changes. How do I update it? I looked at other SO questions but they aren't very helpful..

Comment: Note: `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1.  Could simplify to `int currS = sizeof(arr);`

Comment: Consider using POSIX function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) in place of `fgets()` because one its advantages is that returns the length of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `readIt()` function, you need `strlen(arr)`, not `sizeof arr`. The latter will give you the size of a `char *`, which is always the same, regardless of the length of the string to which it might point.

You should also check that the return from `fopen()` is not `NULL`, since `fopen()` can fail for many reasons.

```
void readIt(char* argv[], char arr[], int currS) {
    FILE * file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if ( file ) {
        while( fgets(arr, currS, file) ) {
            const int len = strlen(arr); 
            for ( int i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
                // print each char of current line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that using the variable `len` here means you only calculate the length of the string once, before you start to loop over it, rather than calculating it every time through the loop which would happen if you did `for ( int i = 0; i < strlen(arr); ++i )`. If all you're doing is printing every character, then the length of the string isn't going to change in between calls to `fgets()`, so it's inefficient to calculate it more than once.

Also, unless for some reason you want the array in `main()` to contain the last line read from the file after `readIt()` returns, you could more easily define `arr` within `readIt()` itself, to avoid the need to pass it to that function at all, for instance:

```
void readIt(char* argv[]) {
    FILE * file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if ( file ) {
        char arr[200];
        while( fgets(arr, sizeof arr, file) ) {
            const int len = strlen(arr); 
            for ( int i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
                // print each char of current line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because `arr` is now an actual array within `readIt()`, rather than a pointer to `char` (you can't pass an array to a function, only the address of one), `sizeof arr` will give you the actual size of the array, rather than the size of a `char *`, so you can pass that to `fgets()`.

Comment: You're a life saver. I have been debugging this for 3 hours. Thank you for the answer and the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
void readIt(char* argv[], char arr[], int currS) {
  FILE* file;
  file = NULL;
  file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  while(fgets(arr, currS, file) != NULL)
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
       print each char of current line
}
```

would be better written to use the actual number of characters in the `arr[]`
Suggest using braces, to avoid many future maintenance headaches
Suggest using vertical spacing for readability
Suggest using comments to avoid many future maintenance headaches

```
void readIt(char* argv[], char arr[], int currS)
{
    FILE* file = NULL;

    if( NULL == (file = fopen(argv[1], "r") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    // read line from file and echo to user
    // note: file lines are considered to be terminated by either a NUL char or newline or EOF
    //       fgets() assures the line in arr[] has a NUL char termination
    while( fgets(arr, currS, file) )
    {
        int len = strlen(arr);  // returns offset to NUL char

        // use following if do not want to echo a newline read from the file
        if( '\n' == arr[strlen(arr)-1])
        {
            arr[strlen(arr)-1] = '\0';
            len--;
        } // end if

        printf( "\nNumber of characters in line: %d\n", len );
        printf( "%s\n", arr );

    } // end while

    fclose(file); // cleanup
} // end function: readIt
```

Comment: "file lines are considered to be terminated by either a NUL char or newline or EOF" is not correct.  File lines end with the `'\n'` or the `EOF` condition.  `fgets()` does not stop reading from a file should it encounter a `'\0'`.